# Discrete subgroups of isometry group $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group. We say that a subgroup $S$ of $G$ is discrete if and only if the subspace topology (from $G$) on
$S$ is discrete.

Note that isometry group of euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is displayed by $E(n)$(or affine isometries on $\mathbb{R}^n  , \  O(n)\subset E(n)$)   and $Sx:=\left\{s(x);\ \forall s\in S\subseteq E(n)\right\}$ is $S$-orbit of any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where S is any subgroup of E(n).

For discrete subgroups S of isometry group of euclidean space $E(n)$  an equivalent
condition is: intersection of the $S$-orbit of any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ has finite intersection with any
compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Why is there a such the equivalent condition? How can I prove it?

Comment: Affine isometries or $O(n)$? Anyway, recall how you definie the topology on $G$

Answer (score 1):

The definition means that $S$ is discrete if for each point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the family $Sx$ is locally finite, i.e., for each point there is a neighbourhood intersecting only finitely many subsets of this family. This is equivalent to the fact each compact set intersects only finitely many subsets of this family.

Comment: To add to this solution: The only properties you need are that the group action is isometric and that closed balls are compact.

Comment: What's your mean from the family $Sx$? Is your mean $\mathcal{F}=\{\text{singleton  subsets of} \ Sx\}$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ that fixed? Why is this family locally finite? I do not figure out The last equivalence. Why are these property only for group action of isometries on $\mathbb{R}^n$? Please describe them more than your posts.

Comment: I mean $Sx=\{s.x \mid s \in S\}$. The word "family" is used in Vinberg's book on discrete groups. Your definition of discrete is just that each Sx is locally finite, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology.

Comment: Dear   Dietrich Burde, My $\mathcal{F}$ is the same with your mean from $Sx=\{s.x\ | s\in S\}$.  Why is this family($\mathcal{F}$) locally finite?  I do not figure out The last your equivalence in your answer. What's Vinberg's book? What's connection the Wikipedia webpage(in the last your comment) with my problem?

Comment: Dear bigli, Vinberg's book: Geometry II. Encyclopedia of Mathematical Sciences, Springer 1991. The definition of the topology answers your question, see the remark of Hagen von Eitzen. But you can find all details in Vinberg's book.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like know that why  any discrete subgroup G of $E(n)$ ( i.e subspace topology (from E(n)) on G is discrete) has locally finite orbits in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and vice versa.