# Discrete subgroups and Discontinuous subgroups of the isometries of the euclidean plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

I am working with subgroups of $\operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (isometries on $\mathbb{R}^2$), and am trying to classify Frieze and Wallpaper groups. I have two books, which use a different word to (from what I can see) mean the same thing:

$G \leqslant \operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is $\textbf{discrete}$ if it does not contain rotations of arbitrarily small angle an no translations of arbitrarily small distance.

$G \leqslant \operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is $\textbf{discontinuous}$ if for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $Orb_{G}(x) \cap U = \{x\} $

Firstly, are these definitions standard? (Are they consistent with more general definitions?). Are they equivalent (I can see how discontinuous $\Rightarrow$ discrete but I don't know about the other way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions are standard. Discrete groups are in general defined as follows:

*Definition:* A *discrete subgroup* of a topological group $G$ is a subgroup $H$ such that there is an open cover of $H$ in which every open subset contains exactly one element of $H$; in other words, the subspace topology of $H$ in $G$ is the discrete topology.

For subgroups of isometries also the following definition is used:
A subgroup $\Gamma\in \operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is called *discrete* if
each orbit $\Gamma x$ for the action of $\Gamma$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The definition is equivalent, for $n=2$, to the given one.

*Definition:* An action of a discrete group $G$ on a topological space $X$ is *properly discontinuous* if and only if $\forall x,y \in X$ there exist neighbourhoods $U_x$ and $U_y$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that the set $\{g \in G : g \cdot U_x \cap U_y\ \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite.

In general, "properly discontinuous" implies "discrete", but the converse is not true in general. It is true, however, for actions of $\operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. See also the question 
[Discrete subgroups of isometry group $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580808/discrete-subgroups-of-isometry-group-mathbbrn).

Comment: The general definition of a proper group action (for non-discrete groups) is that the action is proper if the map $G\times X\to X\times X$, where $(g,x)\mapsto (gx,x)$ is proper, i.e. closed, and preimages of points are compact. (If $G$ is discrete, this is equivalent to the one you have cited.) By the way, you forgot to say that $x\neq y$ in the definition of discontinuity.

Comment: I see, thank you for the help.